# org.slf4j.Logger's isTraceEnabled() method is returning false , but in logback.xml log level is set to "level="TRACE"

Tags: logback, slf4j

I have set log level to "TRACE" in logback.xml.

In my java class i have code like,

```
 if (org.slf4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                org.slf4j.Logger.trace("Log tracing is enabled");
            }
```

But the if loop condition is returning false.

Can anyone help me understand how it works? What i'm doing wrong?

Edit: Created Logger object like,

org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

Is the issue is because i'm using logback and creating object using org.slf4j?

Comment: @glytching this is where i'm setting my log level in logback.xml file. `<root xlevel="${rootLevel}" level="TRACE">
      <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
   <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
          <appender-ref ref="CUSTOMER_REALTTIME_SIFT" />

    </root>`

Comment: @glytching I'm not sure how to provide more information. But i'll try my best to explain you what i did. I have an web application which uses logback for logging. I have set log level to Trace and i'm able to see the trace logs. But the line `org.slf4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()` is returning false, eventhough i enable trace logs.